# How to access object instance from property instance? (in `update` callback)

Tags: python, add-on

I am trying to create an add-on to create parametric objects (Blender 2.8rc1)

I have defined a custom `PropertyGroup`, i.e.:

```
def _update(self, context):
    print(repr(self))

class FurnigenProperties(types.PropertyGroup):
    width: FloatProperty(
        update=_update,
        unit='LENGTH'
    )
    length: FloatProperty(
        update=_update,
        unit='LENGTH'
    )
```

When I change property I can see out of `_update`:

bpy.data.objects['GeneratedObject'].parametric_properties

What I essentially want to get access to would be `bpy.data.objects['GeneratedObject']` however I am unclear how to get from `self` in callback function to actual object that property we just modified.

Looking at documentation for [bpy.props.FloatProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=bpy%20props%20floatproperty#bpy.props.FloatProperty) there isn't much detail on what I should expect `context` to be.

I.e. would `context` be the place to retrieve object reference? I was thinking about `context.object`, but I am not clear how `object` is determined. Is that object selected by user in viewport? In which case it wouldn't work if I modified property from some other Python code (as it would be most likely for a collection of objects of which none would be selected by user).
Or is `context.object` in callback guaranteed to point to object that `self` belongs to in above callback?

**edit**:

`context.object` doesn't seem to work. I just tried setting value of one of my properties through Python console and the object that I get from `context.object` is (as I expected) object selected in viewport and **not** the object I modified property of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`id_data`**

the `id_data` property of any blender object is a refernce to the ID type object it belongs to.

```
def _update(self, context):
    print(self.id_data)
```